# Insert new Row of Real table based upon a loop executed on a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

Obviously this code below is wrong, but you'll have to forgive that as I have not really done loops in SQL before.

```
While (Select oldSysNr, DoW.DoWC, DoW.WorkStart, DoW.WorkEnd, DoW.ContractHours From #TempTable 
Join AppData.TSCHEDDOW as DoW 
On DoW.ShiftSystemNumber = oldSysNr)


    Insert into AppData.TSCHEDDOW 
    (
        #TempTable.newSysNr,
        DoWC,
        WorkStart,
        WorkEnd,
        ContractHours
    )
    Select
    #TempTable.newSysNr,
    DoWC,
    WorkStart,
    WorkEnd,
    ContractHours
    From AppData.TSCHED 
End;
```

The intended result is that this loops through the tempTable's oldSysNr and when that and the AppData.TSCHEDDOW SysNr match, then it would insert new rows into AppData.TSCHED with only newSysNr being the attribute that changes, while keeping the old rows.

Here are the desired results:

```
AppData.TSCHEDDOW
    SysNr   DoWC   WorkStart   WorkEnd  ContractHours
    --------------------------------------------------
    24      1        12:00      8:00         8
    25      2        12:00      8:00         8
    26      2        9:00       6:00         8
    27      5        7:00       3:00         8
    54      1        12:00      8:00         8
    55      2        12:00      8:00         8
    56      2        9:00       6:00         8
    57      5        7:00       3:00         8
```

My question now is what am I doing wrong here with this loop, and what should I be doing instead? Any help that I can get and resources to look at for this question will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Sample Data:

```
#TempTable
oldSysNr     newSysNr
------------------------
24            54
25            55
26            56
27            57

AppData.TSCHEDDOW
        SysNr   DoWC   WorkStart   WorkEnd  ContractHours
        --------------------------------------------------

        24      1        12:00      8:00         8
        25      2        12:00      8:00         8
        26      2        9:00       6:00         8
        27      5        7:00       3:00         8
```

The information in which newSysNr is populated from comes from the same table as oldSysNr, this is the result of a creating a temp table that has self joined based upon a year parameter, one being the year that is copied and the year that all this information will get copied to. If anything else is needed to fully answer this question, please let me know.

Comment: I'm really confused by what you're asking here. and you're SQL doesn't really make sense either. Firstly your `WHILE` doesn't have a boolean result. It's in the format of `WHILE (subquery)` a query doesn't return a boolean value, it returns a dataset. Then you have your statement *"The intended result is that this loops through the tempTable's oldSysNr and when that and the AppData."*. Are you thinking that the process "loops" through every row from that dataset and then does *"something"* with that row? That isn't how an RDBMS works at all.

Comment: SQL isn't a programming language. a `SELECT` statement returns a dataset, and if you want to do *something* to that data, you apply that logic to a column within that dataset, not one row at a time. I think we need to take a step back here, understand your real goal, and then we can show you how you do what you're after in a set based operation. Don't treat SQL like a programming language; it isn't. Programs excel at iterative tasks, DBMS' excel at set-based tasks; and the 2 are very different (both in the way you need to think about them and the way you "write" them).

Comment: It's hard to explain how it is that this is supposed to work, like I said, you'll have to forgive the code as I already know it's wrong. I am essentially asking for the syntax of how I would write a loop that looks at the oldSysNr temptable, compares that with what exists inside the APPSCEDDOW table and its current sysNr. then if those two things are equal each other then, to insert a new row with all the same info that current sysNr has, with the exception that now newSysNr will take the place of oldSysNr.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all you need is a `left join` or a `where` clause with a subquery. I am fairly certain that you don't need a loop unless you're updating the same table as you are selecting from.

Comment: You need to stop thinking in "rows", fast. Like I said, a DBMS works in sets, not row by row.

Answer (score 1):

Provided understand what you are actually describing, I think all you need is a simple `UPDATE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE TSCHEDDOW (SysNr int,
                        DoWC int,
                        WorkStart time,
                        WorkEnd time,
                        ContractHours int)
INSERT INTO TSCHEDDOW
VALUES(24,1,'12:00','8:00',8),
      (25,2,'12:00','8:00',8),
      (26,2,'9:00','6:00',8),
      (27,5,'7:00','3:00',8)

CREATE TABLE #temp (oldSysNr int,newSysNr int)
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES(24,54),
      (25,55),
      (26,56),
      (27,57);

UPDATE TS
SET SysNr = T.newSysNr
FROM TSCHEDDOW TS
     JOIN #temp T ON TS.SysNr = T.oldSysNr
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=537391c692859d9c777b9394a4ec69ce)

*Edit: Here are my "extra" guesses, but otherwise, they need to explain more and show better expected results:*

```
INSERT INTO TSCHEDDOW (SysNr,DoWC, WorkStart, WorkEnd, ContractHours)
SELECT T.newSysNr,
       TS.DoWC,
       TS.WorkStart,
       TS.WorkEnd,
       TS.ContractHours
FROM TSCHEDDOW TS
     JOIN #temp T ON TS.SysNr = T.oldSysNr;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0c86f79dc7fe90635eb4b4f9f0c72f5)

```
ALTER TABLE TSCHEDDOW ADD NewSysNr int;

....

UPDATE TS
SET newSysNr = T.newSysNr
FROM TSCHEDDOW TS
     JOIN #temp T ON TS.SysNr = T.oldSysNr;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=071ddb08aa304568fce3cdabb0335ad0)

Comment: I'm not looking to update as that would override the oldSysNr information, instead I want them inserted alongside the oldSysNr as new sets with the only difference being  newSysNr there instead of oldSysNr.

Comment: So you want a new column @MAG5982? You're not making much sense here.

Comment: no, I am saying that its basically going to be like an insert into select situation. If the oldSysNr and the SysNr from APPSCEDDOW are the same number, then it needs to do an insert into APPSCEDDOW Select the NewSysNr from TempTable along with all the other information(Which remains the same).

Comment: *Maybe* one of those. Otherwise, @MAG5982 it's time for sample data and expected results.